# Force CSS grid to make all the rows their respective height (in fractional units)

Tags: css, css-grid

In my container element, I set `display: grid` and `grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr 1fr`, but the children are able to go beyond the row height. The child in the top row is able to take up almost the entire height of the container grid.
Is there a way (from the container element) to force all of the children to shrink to fit in the `2fr`/`1fr` row height? Or do I have to set that from the child?

Comment: `fr` is equivleent to `minmax(auto, xfr)` instead use `minmax(0, xfr)` in your case it would be `grid-template-rows:minmax(0, 2fr) minmax(0, 2fr) minmax(0, 1fr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Zohir Salak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7148391/zohir-salak) said, `fr` is equivalent to `minmax(auto, xfr)` instead use `minmax(0, xfr)` to fix the problem.
So I fixed it by doing `grid-template-rows:minmax(0, 2fr) minmax(0, 2fr) minmax(0, 1fr)`

Comment: It doesn't save a lot in this instance, but you might as well make full use of Grid's abilities, and employ the [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) function: `repeat(2, minmax(0, 2fr)) minmax(0, 1fr)`